# Fitnesse Trim String data before comparison

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

I wanted to ask if there is a way to trim String data before comparing it with the data in the table. For example, if we have

```
|MyCompareClass|
|getString?    |
|string1       |
```

And the result of getString() will be "string1    ". I want the comparison to be green and not Expected "string1".
I'm looking for a way to do it without modifying the MyCompareClass source code. Any ideas?

Comment: What does MyCompareClass look like?

Comment: i'm talking about any class not that in particular. I want to ignore any whitespaces when comparing the output of getString for example and the expected value 'string1'. We are talking about the output of every method in every class. So i'm looking for a way like to configure fitness so that he trims automatically the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom string compare operator class:

```
public class MyCustomCompare: CellOperator, CompareOperator<Cell> {
    public bool CanCompare(TypedValue actual, Tree<Cell> expected) {
        return actual.Type == typeof(string);
    }

    public bool Compare(TypedValue actual, Tree<Cell> expected) {
        return actual.Value.ToString().Trim() == expected.Value.Text;
    }
}
```

Then register your class with the `Fitnesse` configure fixture:

```
|configure|processor|add operator|MyCustomCompare|
```

Comment: can you explain more about the last part?
    Then register your class with the Fitnesse configure fixture:

    |configure|processor|add operator|MyCustomCompare|

Comment: You need to put this table in a FitNesse page so it knows to use your custom compare class.  Usually you would put this in a SuiteSetUp page if you want it to be used in all your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could put `!-string1 -!` in your cell. All other options I can think of involve code changes to either SUT or fixture.

Comment: can't we maybe override some classes in fitnesse so that the space is removed automatically from the data?